# MySQL How to filter a query based on avoiding a particular result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, mysql-workbench

Here's the simplified equivalent:

Table: 
user_log

Fields:
log_id,
user_id,
log_comment,
log_created,
log_updated

What I tried:

```
    SELECT * FROM user_log 
    WHERE user_id = 123 
    AND log_comment = "The one I want"
    AND NOT log_comment = "The one I don't want"
```

Desired Result:
Ideally I would want it to return all the records from the table for that user id, and none at all if it contains a comment of "The one I don't want".

Actual Result:
Doesn't work. What it does instead is it returns the record with the comment "The one I want".

Sorry if this wasn't clear from the title, I wasn't sure how to describe my problem.

Comment: Your query looks good. Maybe the "one you don't want" comes in different shapes and misspellings?

Comment: @TheImpaler I don't think you've thought this through.

Comment: Just to rephrase a user can have lots of comments some of which may be the one you want and some may be the one you don't want. If there are any of the latter you don't want any at all for that user.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT ul.*
FROM user_log ul
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM user_log ul1 
                  WHERE ul.user_id = ul1.user_id AND ul1.log_comment = "The one I don't want"
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can use conditional aggregation function based filtering using `Group By` and `Having` clause. In a Derived table, we can determine if `user_id = 123` has any row with `log_comment = "The one I don't want"`.
- `HAVING NOT SUM(log_comment = "The one I don't want")` ensures that no such row exists for a user_id.
- Now, simply join this Derived table result-set to the `user_log` table, and get only those rows where `log_comment = "The one I want"`.
- If there is even a single row with "The one I don't want" for the user_id; this query will not return any single row.

Use conditional aggregation with Group By:

```
SELECT u1.* 
FROM user_log AS u1 
JOIN (SELECT u2.user_id 
      FROM user_log AS u2 
      WHERE u2.user_id = 123 
      GROUP BY u2.user_id 
      HAVING NOT SUM(u2.log_comment = "The one I don't want")
     ) AS dt ON dt.user_id = u1.user_id 
WHERE 
  u1.log_comment = "The one I want"
```

Comment: Hm, well maybe something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select ul.*
from user_log ul
where exists (select 1
              from user_log ul2
              where ul2.user_id = ul.user_id and
                    ul2.comment = 'The one I want'
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from user_log ul2
                  where ul2.user_id = ul.user_id and
                        ul2.comment = 'The one I don''t want'
                 ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM user_log 
WHERE user_id = 123 
AND log_comment     LIKE "%The one I want%"
AND log_comment NOT LIKE "%The one I don't want%"
```

As I read your description, here are some examples of `log_comment`

"Hey, The one I want -- yeah!"  -- capture this one
"Hey, The one I want -- yes, The one I want"  -- capture this one
"Hey, The one I don't want -- yeah!"  -- skip this one
"Hey, The one I want.  Oh, wait a minute The one I don't want"  -- skip this one
"The one I don't want Oh, wait -- The one I want" -- also skipped

If those are not the correct results, then clarify your question with a set of examples.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but will this work:

```
SELECT * FROM user_log 
WHERE user_id = 123 
AND log_comment not like "%The one I don't want%"
```

Comment: This will still pick up users that ever have  comment "The one I don't want"

Comment: No, it will only pickup user 123.

Comment: So if this user 123 has multiple comments, and one of them is "The one I don't want", your query will still pick up the user, which is wrong.

Comment: OP wants user that has never that "The one I don't want" in the log.

Comment: How can `not like "%The one I don't want%"` pickup "The one I don't want"?

Comment: Run your query using this.  If your query returns result, that means it's wrong. `CREATE TABLE #user_log(user_id INT, log_comment VARCHAR(1000))

INSERT INTO #user_log VALUES (123, 'The one I do not want')
INSERT INTO #user_log VALUES (123, 'The one I want')`

Comment: change `don't` to `do not`